# Brachah on Tefillin, Mezuzah, and Terumah

Tags: blessing, tefilin, mezuzah, teruma

When sitting in the Sukkah, we make a brachah of "leishev baSukkah," reflective of the passuk of "basukkos teishvu shiv'as yamim" (Vayikra 23).

Similarly, when putting up a ma'akeh, we make a brachah of "la'asos ma'akeh," as the passuk says, "v'asisa ma'akeh l'gagecha" (Devarim 22).

Why, then, do we say "l'haniach tefillin" instead of "lehakshir tefillin," like the passuk of "ukeshartam l'os al yadecha" (Devarim 6)?

Likewise, why do we say "likvo'a mezuzah" instead of "l'kasev mezuzah," like the passuk of "u'kesavtam al mezuzos beisecha" (Devarim 6)?

Finally, why do we say "l'hafrish terumah" instead of "l'terom terumah," as in the passuk of "tarimu terumah laHashem" (Bamidbar 18)?

All brachos can be found in the Artscroll Siddur.

Comment: When you attach a Mezuza you aren't writing it and when you separate Terumah you aren't giving it. Why would you say "to write a Mezuza" just before attaching a written Mezuzah to a wall?? Clearly the wording of the verse is not what's at play.

Comment: The mitzvah of mezuzah is to "write" the Mezuzah on the wall, and we fulfill this by taking a written mezuzah and putting it on the wall. Does the fact that it's already written change the fact that the mitzvah of to "write" it? Likewise, does the fact that, b'zman hazeh, we burn terumah instead of giving it to the local Orthodox Kohen change the fact that the mitzvah is to give it?

Comment: You just made that up. The mitzvah is to attach and to separate. (Some think there's an additional mitzvah to give it.)

Comment: The passuk still says ukesavtam and tarimu. Do you have a source that it's not to be taken at face value?

Comment: Yes. Talmud. Rambam. Shulchan Arukh. You need to better support your contention that the wording of the blessing is based on the wording in the verse. You have two examples, both of which could easily be coincidence as those are normal words to use in those contexts and are so used throughout rabbinic literature.

Comment: Why focus on these 5 blessings? There are also blessings on Milah, Tzitzit, candle lighting, hand washing, counting Omer, Torah study, Duchening, Hallel, Lulav, Bedikat Chametz, Matza, Maror, Eruv, Shofar, Shechita, Kisui HaDam, Yibbum, Tevilah, as well as Pidyonei Bechor Adam, Bechor Behemah Temeah, Maaser Sheni, and Revai.

Comment: Good btw. for Tefilin lehoniach with a kamats. I think that it is not the same meaning than lehaniach

Comment: @DoubleAA I was looking for a list of mitzvah Brachos and couldn't find one. These were just the ones off the top of my head, except for tzitzis where I wasn't sure whether to include it or not since it's not a chiyuv.

Comment: So you are basing your premise that blessings are based on verses on just two blessings without checking the dozens of others? Do you see why this is a very weak question?

Comment: I'll take a look later when I get a chance and mark to close if I can't find more to support my question.

Comment: Alright. So I went through your list @DoubleAA. Most of the ones were either d'Rabbanan, or v'tzivanu al <name of mitzvah> without a verb to compare, or the brachah was different because the mitzvah isn't as presented in the passuk (such as your question with my question earlier regarding terumah and mezuzah). That left four mitzvos whose verbs matched up - Sukkah, Maakeh, Omer, and Matzah - and four that didn't - Tefillin, Maaser Sheini, Lulav, and Biur Chameitz. Since its split evenly, there's no conclusive proof one way or another. Voting to close.